# How can I save multiple entries to a list and then print a random entry from that list?

Tags: list, tkinter, random

Hello i can only seem to print letters from an entry not the full entry (sentence).

I simply want to click a button using tkinter and after typing a sentence into a box, the button will store the sentences in a list.

Then I want to create a second button that will then print a random sentence from that list.

When I try this it only prints letters of the stored sentence.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as I’ve looked around for the last two days before asking.

Best wishes to you all

```
from tkinter import *

import random

def super_function():
    out = map(Entry.get, entr)
    clear_entry_1()

def clear_entry_1():
    Entry_field.delete(0,END)

def super_function_2():
    print(random.choice(entr))

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
entr = []

for i in range(10):
    entr.append(Entry(root))

Entry_field = Entry()
Entry_field.pack()


Button1 = Button(root, text = 'Add your idea!', command = 
super_function)
Button1.pack()
Button2 = Button(root, text='Generate an idea!', 
command=super_function_2)
Button2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry here is my code -

Comment: I updated the current code im trying, i have edited it like 15 times but can't get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop is useless and should be removed as it just appends 10 invisible entries.

What you need is to append the sentence inside `super_function()` instead:

```py
def super_function():
    # save the sentence
    entr.append(Entry_field.get())
    clear_entry_1()
```

Comment: Thank you! This has really helped, however i can only print the entries in the terminal as of yet. I am trying to use a label.config to update the text in the label with a random sentence from the entr list, but the print statement is conflicting with the text alteration in the .config change. Thank you i can finally see a way out of this hole!